# Ad server / access div inside of html iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

When the id="expand-box" is clicked in the iframe I would like to make the outside div id="ad-wrapper" in the window to get larger in height. Breaker file added to publisher site.

Comment: it seems you have misunderstood how this site works. It is up to you to provide code attempts and demos. It's not hard to find similar issues in a google search. Start there and come back when you have some code that isn't working quite right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I was looking for:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 if(top==self){
 /* The creative is not in an iframe. Display the ad. It might be possible to use document.write      to display the creative. */
 }else{
 try{
 /* Use appropriate code to have the creative escape the iframe and show the ad. Most likely the code will need to use DOM functions and reference the top window. */
 }catch(e){
 /* The creative cannot escape the iframe. Show an appropriate alternative. The alternative will remain inside of the iframe. */
 }
 }
 </script>
```

I found these links very helpful!
http://clearcode.cc/2013/02/ad-serving-insights-ad-invocation-codes-and-placement-tags/
[Yet Another cross-domain iframe resize Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908676/yet-another-cross-domain-iframe-resize-qa)
[How do iframe busters for expandable ads work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553469/how-do-iframe-busters-for-expandable-ads-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the iframe events in your main html like:-

```
$('iframe').contents().find('#expand-box').bind('click', function( event ) {
$('#ad-wrapper').height(500);
});
```