# DoubleClick For Publishers (DFP) : Serving expandable ads using asynchronous GPT

Tags: iframe, asynchronous, google-dfp, rich-media

I'm using an asynchronous GPT to serve my expandable ad, but the creative is getting cut off because it seems that the asynchronous tags are not friendly iframes.

I used the DOM function to escape the iframe parent, but I think that i can't because the creative is rendering before the rendering of the page.

This is a sample of my tags

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.googletagservices.com/tag/js/gpt.js'>
    googletag.pubads().definePassback('6917646/H24info/H24INFO_ATF_HOME_728x90', [[728,90]]).setClickUrl('[INSERT_CLICK_COUNTER_HERE]').display();

    googletag.pubads().enableSingleRequest(); 
    googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {

        var sas = document.getElementById("sas_format_33008");

        var gpt = document.getElementById("gpt_unit_6917646/H24info/H24INFO_ATF_HOME_728x90_1_ad_container");

        gpt.style.position = "absolute";
        gpt.style.zIndex = "100";

        sas.style.height = "90px";
    });
    googletag.enableServices();
</script>
```

Is there somebody who can help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use Post Messages. But you will need to put an event listener in your main site.
Something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        function onMessageReceived(e) {
            if (
                //e.origin !== 'http://tpc.googlesyndication.com' ||
                typeof e.data !== 'object' ||
                typeof e.data.id !== 'string' ||
                e.data.cmd !== 'setStyle' ||
                typeof e.data.params !== 'object'
            ) {
                return;
            }

            var frame = document.getElementById(e.data.id);

            if (frame === null) {
                return;
            }

            Object.keys(e.data.params).forEach(function(param) {
                frame.style[param] = e.data.params[param];
            });
        }

        if (window.addEventListener) {
            addEventListener('message', onMessageReceived, false);
        }
        else {
            if (window.attachEvent) {
                attachEvent('onmessage', onMessageReceived);
            }
            else {
                window.onmessage = onMessageReceived;
            }
        }
    })();
</script>
```

Then in the creative code, you will have to call the event listener to resize the elements that you need to expand. For example:

```
<script>
(function(){
    if (window.top.postMessage) {
        window.top.postMessage({
            cmd: 'setStyle',
            id: 'div-of-the-banner',
            params: {
                display: 'block',
                height: '600px',
                width: '300px'
            }
        }, '*');
    }
})();
</script>
```

You may need to call this resize script several times if more than one element is actually fixing the size of your creative.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an iframe buster

You can try the code below. Remember that you will need to uncheck the "Serve into a SafeFrame" config in creative settings. The type of the creative must be Custom, Third-Party or a template)

```
if (top === self) {
        // 
} else {
    var parentIframes = top.document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
    for (var i=0; i < parentIframes.length; i++) {
        var el = parentIframes[i];
        if (el.contentWindow === self) {
            // here you can create an expandable ad
            var expandableAd;

            var googleDiv = el.parentNode;

            googleDiv.insertBefore(expandableAd, el);

        }
    }
}
```

More information:

- [Iframe Buster purpose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792842/iframe-buster-files-whats-their-purpose)
- [Working with Friendly Frames](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/2557031)

More help:

- [Choosing the GPT mode](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/183282?hl=en)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no iFrame Buster for GPT Tags ( available only for DART tags ).